# thumbnail not displaying when i open view in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I am trying to display thumbnail of videos and i am fetching the thumbnail url from firebase and using Image.network to display them but the thumbnail are not displaying on the first they only came when i hot reload
I am calling the fetch ThumbnailUrls like this

```
class _XtreamTubeState extends State<XtreamTube> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchThumbnailUrls();
  }
```

I am displaying the thumbnails like this

```
  
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> thumbnailUrl;

  const HomeScreen({super.key, required this.thumbnailUrl});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const CustomSliverTubeAppBar(),
          SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) {
              final video = thumbnailUrl[index];
              print('video$video');

              return VideoContainer(videoUrl: video);
            },
            childCount: thumbnailUrl.length,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried a lot of thing

Comment: Obviously, _fetchThumbnailUrls() does not have time to fetch the data before the screen is rendered. the data arrives after. try futurebuilder

Comment: here is the function 
  void _fetchThumbnailUrls() async {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = collection.snapshots();

    stream.listen((snapshot) {
      for (DocumentSnapshot doc in snapshot.docs) {
        final thumbnailUrl = doc['thumbnailUrl'];

        setState(() {
          thumbnailUrls.add(thumbnailUrl);
        });
      }
    });
  }

Answer (score 1):

i think in the build the thumbnailUrl list should not be empty and that is causing the improper rendering
so try this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (thumbnailUrl.isEmpty) {
    return ProgressIndicator(); // <--pass something to keep in rendering 
                                //untill thumbnailUrl.isEmpty is false
  } else {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          const CustomSliverTubeAppBar(),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (context, index) {
                final video = thumbnailUrl[index];
                print('video$video');
                return VideoContainer(videoUrl: video);
              },
              childCount: thumbnailUrl.length,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

other approach :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: _fetchThumbnailUrls(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (thumbnailUrl.isEmpty) {
    return ProgressIndicator(); 
           } else {
          final thumbnailUrls = snapshot.data;
          return CustomScrollView(
            slivers: [
              const CustomSliverTubeAppBar(),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                  (context, index) {
                    final video = thumbnailUrls[index];
                    print('video$video');
                    return VideoContainer(videoUrl: video);
                  },
                  childCount: thumbnailUrls.length,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks to @Vladyslav Ulianytskyi for highlighting the cause , please let us know what workes best for you so that i can update my answer base on it

Comment: I have updated the question I am displaying the thumbnails using stateless widget

Comment: and as you can see i am calling _fetchThumbnailUrls(); when the view is opend so the list should not be empty
 class _XtreamTubeState extends State<XtreamTube> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchThumbnailUrls();
  }